# Jquery time picker strange behavior

Tags: javascript, jquery, frontend, timepicker

the setting

```
var alternateScheduleTimePickerSetting = {
    'timeFormat' : 'h:mm p',
    'startTime' : '06:00 AM'
}// same if remove quote around timeFormat and startTime
```

usage is here

```
$(('#alternateDayStartTime'+i)).timepicker(alternateScheduleTimePickerSetting)

$(('#alternateDayEndTime'+i)).timepicker(alternateScheduleTimePickerSetting)
```

But I get this as a dropdown list

```
12:mm p
1:mm p
2:mm p 
3:mm p
.... etc
```

Something is wrong here that minute and AM/PM is not rendered at all. Start time is not taking effect as well. Any ideas?

i is just to select the id, nothing fancy

Comment: what happens if you remove the quotes around timeFormat and startTime?

Comment: @mjw smae thing

Comment: Can you make a fiddle?

Comment: Which jQuery timepicker are you even talking about? There are several.

Comment: @CBroe Was that you that pointed out the PHP format thing? you are right I was looking at a wrong documentation for this plugin. New to the codebase lol. Thanks ya all

Comment: Yeah, I assumed you might be talking about this one here, https://github.com/jonthornton/jquery-timepicker#timepicker-plugin-for-jquery, but wasn't sure.